# Implementing auto autocomplete for CLI application

Tags: go, command-line-interface

I am looking into writing a CLI application in Go.

One of the requirements is auto complete. Not of the command itself but of possible options.

Imagine I want to add a new entry using the CLI. Each entry can have a category.
The categories are available in a slice. What I want to do now is to enable the user to tab through the available categories when typing in `add`.

I am aware of libraries like https://github.com/chzyer/readline and https://github.com/spf13/cobra but could not find if or how they support this.

Comment: What do you mean by "CLI"? Ie will the user start your program and then work in "interacive shell" in it or will the user enter the full command in the system shell and your program does it's thing and exits?

Comment: @ain Good question. I haven't thought about this. It doesn't matter to the use case. Therefore: Whatever is better to implement.

Comment: The two examples you pointed to are very different, one _is_ a readline implementation, and one uses the autocompletion features of bash (which uses a different readline implementation).

Comment: @JimB Could you explain the meaning of readline further?
Does it read the actually line (in the sense of what is/was typed on the CLI) or can I provide the values it should go through?

Comment: readline is a standard library used by interactive CLIs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline

Comment: @Chris The readline package is the solution for "interactive shell" case, the cobra package is for the "user enters the command in system shell and program exits after doing it's thing" case.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @ain and @JimB for pointing me in the right direction.

Based on the example provided at https://github.com/chzyer/readline/tree/master/example/readline-demo I was able to achieve the desired functionality.

The following code has to main commands `newEntry` and `newCategory`. If the user types `newEntry` and than presses TAB he can choose from the available categories. The `newCategory` command allow to add a new custom category which is immediately available the next time `newEntry` is executed.

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "strconv"
    "strings"

    "github.com/chzyer/readline"
)

// completer defines which commands the user can use
var completer = readline.NewPrefixCompleter()

// categories holding the initial default categories. The user can  add categories.
var categories = []string{"Category A", "Category B", "Category C"}

var l *readline.Instance

func main() {

// Initialize config
config := readline.Config{
    Prompt:          "\033[31m»\033[0m ",
    HistoryFile:     "/tmp/readline.tmp",
    AutoComplete:    completer,
    InterruptPrompt: "^C",
    EOFPrompt:       "exit",

    HistorySearchFold: true,
}

var err error
// Create instance
l, err = readline.NewEx(&config)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer l.Close()

// Initial initialization of the completer
updateCompleter(categories)

log.SetOutput(l.Stderr())
// This loop watches for user input and process it
for {
    line, err := l.Readline()
    if err == readline.ErrInterrupt {
        if len(line) == 0 {
            break
        } else {
            continue
        }
    } else if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }

    line = strings.TrimSpace(line)
    // Checking which command the user typed
    switch {
    // Add new category
    case strings.HasPrefix(line, "newCategory"):
        // Remove the "newCategory " prefix (including space)
        if len(line) <= 12 {
            log.Println("newCategory <NameOfCategory>")
            break
        }
        // Append everything that comes behind the command as the name of the new category
        categories = append(categories, line[12:])
        // Update the completer to make the new category available in the cmd
        updateCompleter(categories)
    // Program is closed when user types "exit"
    case line == "exit":
        goto exit
    // Log all commands we don't know
    default:
        log.Println("Unknown command:", strconv.Quote(line))
    }
}
exit:
}

// updateCompleter is updates the completer allowing to add new command during runtime. The completer is recreated
// and the configuration of the instance update.
func updateCompleter(categories []string) {

var items []readline.PrefixCompleterInterface

for _, category := range categories {
    items = append(items, readline.PcItem(category))
}

completer = readline.NewPrefixCompleter(
    readline.PcItem("newEntry",
        items...,
    ),
    readline.PcItem("newCategory"),
)

l.Config.AutoComplete = completer
}
```